# Using Google voice and video chat plugin to record voice

Tags: java, audio-recording

I'm trying to develop an application that records audio from the browser. Can I use the Google vioce and video chat plugin that Gmail internally uses to record audio? 
If yes, How can I do this?
If no, is there any other way I can record audio using J2EE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Flash seems to be your only realistic option.